# Spring-boot oauth2 remote server integration test

Tags: rest, oauth, oauth-2.0, spring-boot, integration-testing

I've got a problem with integration tests in spring boot which use remote oauth2 server.

There is one additional profile called *test*.

Here is the class with oauth2 configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class Oauth2serverconf {

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ServiceProperties serviceProperties;

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        final RemoteTokenServices tokenServices = new RemoteTokenServices();
        tokenServices.setClientId(myConfig.getClientId());
        tokenServices.setClientSecret(myConfig.getClientSecret());
        tokenServices.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl(myConfig.getAuthServiceUrl());

        resources.tokenServices(tokenServices);
        resources.resourceId(myConfig.getAuthResourceId());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/some_record/**")
            .hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "USER")
            .anyRequest()
            .permitAll();
    }
}
```

}

For test I am using fake Oauth server that works which means that I can get response from REST GET (and others) methods in test and get fake token:

```
@RestController
@Profile("test")
public class AuthMockController {

@RequestMapping("/oauth/token")
public String getToken() {
    return "TEST_TOKEN";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/oauth/check_token", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String GETcheckToken() {
    return validateToken();
}

private String validateToken() {
    //there is real response from real oauth server
    return "....";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/oauth/check_token", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public String DELETEcheckToken() {
    return validateToken();
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/oauth/check_token", method = RequestMethod.HEAD)
public String HEADcheckToken() {
    return validateToken();
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/oauth/check_token", method = RequestMethod.OPTIONS)
public String OPTIONScheckToken() {
    return validateToken();
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/oauth/check_token", method = RequestMethod.PATCH)
public String PATCHcheckToken() {
    return validateToken();
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/oauth/check_token", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String POSTcheckToken() {
    return validateToken();
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/oauth/check_token", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public String PUTcheckToken() {
    return validateToken();
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/oauth/check_token", method = RequestMethod.TRACE)
public String TRACEcheckToken() {
    return validateToken();
}
```

}

Here are my application-test.properties:

```
clientSecret= secret //required for access token
clientId= id
authServiceUrl = http://localhost:${server.port}/oauth/check_token
authResourceId = some_resource_id
```

So, when I run this test:

```
 @Test
public void test1() {
    String response = template.getForObject("http://localhost:"+port+"/oauth/token", String.class);

    System.err.println(response);
}
```

I get TEST_TOKEN in the response, so the REST works fine.

The problem is that when I call the real REST service in my application, which needs oauth2 token I get 401 error code. When I manually run the application and pass valid access token everything works fine.
Here is failing test:

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    final String pageSize = "1";
    final String resource = base.toString() + "/some_record?pageSize=" + pageSize;

    final ResponseEntity<String> response = template.exchange(resource, HttpMethod.GET, null, someResponseType);

    assertThat(response.getBody()).isNotEmpty();
    assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I would be grateful for any help.